# shinyDashboard; Maximizing tabBox with a sidebar will add a horizontal Scrollbar to the box?

Tags: css, r, scrollbar, shinydashboard, box

I am using a sidebar inside a box in shinyDashboard, which is working perfectly. However when I maximize the box, it will add an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar to the box. I tried disabling it with the following CSS style code:

```
tags$style("body {overflow-x: hidden !important; }")
```

But it does not work. Does anyone know how to remove the scrollbar?
Here is a simple reproducible code:

```
# Toggle a box sidebar
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$style("body {overflow-x: hidden !important; }"),
      box(
        height = "500px",
        width = 12,
        maximizable = T,
        solidHeader = FALSE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        sidebar = boxSidebar(
          id = "mycardsidebar",
          width = 30,
          p("Sidebar Content")
        )
      )
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing what you described. In your description of the problem you mention shinyDashboard, but in your code you are calling library(bs4Dash), is it possible that you are experiencing a package conflict if both are loaded?

Comment: Thanks @SusanSwitzer for the comment. Sorry for confusion. It is actually bs4Dash which is from the same family as shinyDashboard. I cleaned my Environment and restart my R session, but it still the same issue. The x-scrollbar appears when I maximize the tabBox. I am adding a clip here to show what I am talking about.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried refining the css a bit

```
  # Toggle a box sidebar
  library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$style(".card.maximized-card .card-body {overflow-x: hidden !important; }"),
      box(
        height = "500px",
        width = 12,
        maximizable = T,
        solidHeader = FALSE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        sidebar = boxSidebar(
          id = "mycardsidebar",
          width = 30,
          p("Sidebar Content")
        )
      )
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SusanSwitzer. it works with this also:
```
tags$style(".card-body {overflow: hidden !important; }")
```
So ".card.maximized-card" is unnecessary. 
Appreciate your help.